# How to use SonarLint connected mode for custom configured rules in STS

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I have a `SonarQube` server up and running which has custom rules configured which needs to be reflected in `SonarLint`. I have run a `SonarQube` scan, and the projects are being shown in https://localhost:9000 UI screen.

lets come to the `SonarLint`. Without binding the project, I am getting issues as per default rules configured in `SonarLint`.

But when I bind the module with the `SonarQube` project, issues are not showing up. Its not even single violation in any one of class.

Please guide me to use the feature.

Comment: What is the 'STS' in the title?

Comment: its IDE,STS  version 3.7.3(Spring Tool Suite)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have considered below solution already, if not please go throw by below suggestion once and give a try :

You can use the connected mode to bind your project in the IDE to a project in `SonarQube`. `SonarLint` will use the same code analyzers and rules as the ones in `SonarQube`. In `SonarQube`, it's possible to change the quality profile assigned to projects and `enable/disable` rules also.

**More information**: http://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/index.html#Connected